# Change background image with a toggle (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do i turn this into a toggle button? So that when the button is clicked, it toggles the light and dark background.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
       $(".content1").css("background-image", "url(../images/light.png)");  
   });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.content1 {
background-image: url('../images/dark.png');
}
```

Thanks

Comment: toggle a class...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Toggle a class instead of setting the background directly. It will be easier to maintain and to know what state the code is in.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(".content1").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.content1 {
  background-image: url('../images/dark.png');
  background-color: red;
}
.content1.active {
  background-image: url('../images/light.png');
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Clicky</button>
<div class="content1"> Hello </div>
```